Trying to find an animated film that told the story of King Arthur
I can't find this film anywhere online, nor does anyone I have asked have any recollection of such a story.
The crucial plot point I remember is this:
Near the end of the movie, the villain (assumedly Mordred), frustrated with his inability to wield Excalibur (due to it burning his hand as he is not the rightful wielder), chops of his own hand and welds Excalibur to his wrist. I have a particular memory that he had the ability to spin Excalibur when it was in this state.
This movie must have come out more than 10 years ago, since that is roughly when I remember seeing it.

I have marked your question as a duplicate of another. You have a good question, and this is not meant to reflect on that, but we have a policy for merging duplicate [tag:story-identification] questions that share an answer.

Maybe Quest for Camelot?

Set in a Celtic mythology, Sir Lionel is a knight of the Round Table, who is killed foiling an assassination attempt on King Arthur by the evil Lord Ruber, who is then driven off by Excalibur, Arthur's sword. Later, while at Lionel's funeral, Arthur tells Lionel's daughter, Kayley, and his widow, Juliana, that they will always be welcome at Camelot. Kayley dreams of becoming a Knight, like her father, and trains herself while working on their farm.

The antagonist with Excalibur fused to his arm:

